# How to pass the jquery variable into the input as a attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

How to add the Jquery or Javascript variable into the input attribute. Whether it is possible or not?

```
var name="Jack";
$("input[type=radio][name=name]").attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: $("input[type=radio][name="+name+"]").attr('disabled', true);

Comment: ``$(`input[type=radio][name=${name}]`).attr('disabled', true);``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var name="Jack";
$("input[type=radio][name="+name+"]").attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotes around your attribute selector value. Further, `name=name` does not "insert" the variable's value as you intend to. You can use backticks (template literals) to do so. The following example only selects the input with name="foo" (jQuery $ does the same):

```js
const name = "foo"
console.log(document.querySelector(`input[type="radio"][name="${name}"]`))
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="foo" />

<input type="radio" name="bar" />
```